# Express static serve vs. Webpack

Tags: node.js, rest, express, webpack, babeljs

Recently I have been thinking about the React app creation and serve ways.
There three most popular ways to run that app on internet:

1. Simply build and run index.html
2. Build and serve index.html with express.static
3. Create app using webpack and babel

What is the creation differences?
What is the best way to do it?
Can I have backend logic only by using webpack? Have I missed some other way how to create react app?

Comment: There is only one good/right choice and that is using Webpack and babel. Why this is I elaborated in an answer but Express is server side and you talk about react and that is frontend. If both server and a back-end/server side Express app is also included to serve an API this together with a React app, best practice would be to divide the code in different directories and for this I would be using Docker btw...

Comment: A very good react app boilerplate for example is https://www.reactboilerplate.com/ or an example of Dockerized Full Stack Mongodb/Express API/React App and server nginx configuration etc can be found https://github.com/denisolek/docker-node-mongo-react-STARTER

Answer (score -1):

If you mean only to serve in production then create an Express JS server to serve your production build. But you will still need to build the source code so since I use Webpack during development I prefer **Webpack** and add the Express JS server files to a separate directory called **server** where you create, setup and configure your Express JS static server this with maybe a separate config file to add ***logger, port, argv*** to the server directory and also place server related middlewares to a directory **middlewares** under **server** directory for the different environments so could be **addDevMiddlewares.js**, **addProdMiddlewares.js** and the **frontendMiddleware.js**. Then just use the server for all environments for example: ***"start:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server*** and ***start: cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server***. It provides/include a number of things. It will **transpile, lint, minify, compress** with gzip for production and **babel** will make sure that your code is transpiled to an earlier compatible version of Vanilla JS like ES5 to support older browsers when you write code using ES6 methods/functions and syntax and I know you will like to use ES6 if not writing TypeScript.

**Webpack** also includes copying resources to the build folder such as images, video and more...

During development you can use webpack mode '***development***' which will automatically set the ***NODE_ENV*** to dev and not minify and compress the **bundle.js** file for debugging purposes. Webpack also has a dev server with hot reload functionality. When building your app to static HTML/CSS and JS files.

Calling index.html will not work since you should be calling a JavaScript file **index.js** or **app.js** and this is specified inside **webpack.dev.babel.js** and **webpack.prod.babel.js** which extend a base or general webpack configuration for example inside **webpack.base.babel.js** which will import/require the **index.html** file as template using ***HtmlWebpackPlugin***. How you structure or split your templates into logical components is kinda up to you. You can put all in one template file **index.html** but it can also just contain the only element needed which can/should be a simple `<div id="app"></div>`
Cause maybe the header and footer files can contain doctype, head and start of body with inside the body for example a  tag with the warning that if they see this text that JavaScript has been disabled in their browser.

Webpack and more specific ***HtmlWebpackPlugin*** will automatically inject all assets such as **bundle.js(.gz)**, **main.css**, etc... with the correct HTML tags. In newer versions of Webpack, don't forget to manually add the plugins needed such as **html-webpack-plugin, terser-webpack-plugin, webpack-cli,** some middlewares for Webpack:  **webpack-dev-middleware, webpack-dev-middleware** and **webpack-pwa-manifest** are some of the most used and important ones.

Hope this helps you understanding why webpack and babel are almost a MUST for frontend applications, babel and even webpack should not be used for native NodeJS server side code since it is a best practice to write as much natively supported NodeJS code certainly since ***Async/Await***, usage of ***classes***, ***Promises*** and many *new Array and itterable* methods like '**map**', '**filter**', '**reduce**', **Array.from()** or '**includes**' are natively supported as of node 7.1.x I thought.

Answer (score -2):

> 1. Simply build and run index.html

I assume you mean without a server.  This works okay enough if you don't need to use any secure resources or server-side resources.  It also means that to load the page, you need to have a copy of the file and associated files.

> 2. Build and serve index.html with express.static

This only differs by #1 in that a server takes care of sending those files to the browser.  This is convenient as you can actually have a URL to go to externally, and it also potentially enables your code to access secure resources online.

> 3. Create app using webpack and babel

This is tangential to how you serve your files.  You still probably want/need a server.  It's totally unrelated to whether or not you use Express.

> What is the best way to do it?

Depends on your needs.  Personally, I find Webpack to be a total hassle so after a couple years of messing with it and wasting time on configuring it, I switched back to Browserify.  But, there are plenty of people who like Webpack, and there is definitely an ecosystem of plugins available for it which you may find useful for your project.  Use what you need.

> Can I have backend logic only by using webpack?

Totally, completely, 100% unrelated.  Webpack is used to make your client-side bundles.  What you use server-side has nothing to do with it.

> Have I missed some other way how to create react app?

You can just use React and Babel.  No need for Webpack technically, but Webpack or equivalent tooling will make your life much easier.